# "Solution (0) projects" when creating an ASP.NET Core Web App (MVC) Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, ide

Visual Studio 2019 here, Community Edition, latest update.

Whenever I try to create a project using the template "ASP.NET Core WEB App (Model View-Controller)" it creates nothing. It shows me "Solution [name] (0) project (see the image below)

[image]

What is the problem? I uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio to no avail. .NetCore web development platform workload and asp.net workload are both installed.

Here's some screenshots of the installer => https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8x08.jpg
Here - it looks like it creates some files in the specified location, but nothing shows in solution explorer at all => https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbWA2.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**// EDIT - FOUND HOW TO FIX IT**

Basically, the solution (in my case) was the following:
Windows => Edit Environmental Variables => System Variables => Path
And there, for some reason, I had two paths to donet. C:\Program Files\dotnet and C:\Porgram Files (x86)\dotnet. I deleted the later and now everything works!
Here's a photo of what to modify.
[image]